# func.bind(thing)(arg) vs func.bind(thing, arg)

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between binding a thing to a function and call it like this

```
func.bind(thing)(arg);
```

and doing it via bind

```
func.bind(thing, arg);
```

? I've been doing the former and it's been working. I believe it's the same thing, but I could be wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a constructor function and an object of it, like this

```
function Arith(operand1) {
    this.operand1 = operand1;
    this.adder = function(operand2) {
        return this.operand1 + operand2;
    }
}

var arith = new Arith(5);
```

Now, for the demonstration purpose, lets create another function which we invoke like this

```
invoker(arith.adder, arith);
```

Now, the `invoker` function invokes the function with two different ways you mentioned in the question

```
function invoker(func, thisArg) {
    console.log(func.bind(thisArg)(6));    // 11
    console.log(func.bind(thisArg, 6)());  // 11
    console.log(func.bind(thisArg)());     // NaN
}
```

So, when you say `func.bind(thisArg)` you are creating a function bound to `thisArg` and you call it with `6` as the parameter. It is roughly equivalent to

```
(function(operand2) {
    thisArg.func(operand2);
}(6))
```

But when you say `func.bind(thisArg, 6)` you are creating a function which is bound to `thisArg` and also you are passing the first parameter to be passed to that function when invoked. So, you can use `Function.prototype.bind` like this to do [partial application of a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions). It is roughly equivalent to

```
(function() {
    thisArg.func(6);
}())
```

In the last case, `NaN` is returned because we don't pass the value for `operand2` of `adder` function, so by default `undefined` is used instead. Adding `undefined` to a number will be `NaN` in JavaScript. It is roughly equivalent to

```
(function() {
    thisArg.func();
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

`func(arg).bind(thing);` `bind` applies to the result of `func(arg)`.

`func.bind(thing, arg);` sets `this` context in `func` to `thing`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake. I meant `func.bind(thing)(arg)`